# Best prepaid SIM card to call Nigeria from Canada

Tags: canada

I will be in Canada for a visit lasting about one month in August 2018. I will need the most affordable prepaid SIM to call Nigeria while in Canada. Some data will be desirable but not a priority. Please advise the best priced SIM. Regards.

Comment: No Canadian prepaid services have particularly good calling rates overseas.  You will be best to get a generic mobile phone account here, as well as an overseas calling card with good African calling rates (most work via toll-free numbers so can be called from anywhere in Canada).

Answer (score 0):

International phone connections are usually ridiculously expensive. The best option is either to use SIM dedicated for international calls (like Lebara, no idea if it's available in Canada) or use VOIP services like Skype (effectively, Lebara etc. are VOIPs).

So your option is to buy any SIM card with good data package and configure App for voip calls and fill it with enough credits. You're unlikely to find anything cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use your local (Nigerian) carrier's roaming service instead? All four of the main service providers in the country allow roaming service from Canada to Nigeria.

Glo: ["Roaming FAQs"](http://www.gloworld.com/ng/personal/roaming/roaming-faqs/)

9Mobile: ["Roaming Offers"](http://9mobile.com.ng/general-offerings/roaming/roaming-offers/)

AirTel Nigeria: ["Roaming with AirTel"](http://www.africa.airtel.com/wps/wcm/connect/africarevamp/nigeria/home/personal/premier/roaming)